# How to create SID like S-1-5-21-123697389-1196883430-1112475604-1016 in windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, sid

I need to create SID like above to change ownership of a Volume. I have used `AllocateAndInitializeSid()` to generate Unknown SID, but what to pass as Subauthority value in this function.

My code is as below :

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID pSIDUnknown = NULL;  
AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2,
        SECURITY_NT_NON_UNIQUE,
        DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pSIDUnknown))
```

It generates SID like  `S-1-5-21-500` BUT I want to generate SID like this format `S-1-5-21-123697389-1196883430-1112475604-1016`

So how to do in windows c++?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating an arbitrary SID structure is trivial. The hard part is creating a custom access token that includes that SID as one of its enabled groups (e.g. via [`LogonUserExExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/logonuserexexw) with SeTcbPrivilege enabled). This is the only way your custom SID can be meaningful in the DACL of secured objects.

Comment: I notice in your code you are using "DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS" and in your SID you are getting the prefix "S-1-5-21-500".  This is because "500" denotes administrator accounts.  To get the format you desire, you'll need to find out which group is represented by "123697389".  Each portion of the SID represents a part of the "environment".  Such as groups, domain, username, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can't just generate your own random SID. SID's are created by Windows. `AllocateAndInitializeSid` is documented as "allocates and initializes a security identifier (SID)" but that allocates and initializes the memory at `**pSIDUnknown`. You're already supposed to have the values from some other source.

The usual way is to just accept a user name and look up its SID with [`LookupAccountNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountnamew)

Comment: I want to create in this format `S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-RID`

Comment: If don't want to create users and then see corresponding SID, I just want to create a unknown SID. Like any other Antivirus software creates a random SID and take ownership on our Files&Folders with that SID.

Comment: Let me reformulate my first sentence then. You CANNOT CREATE them, not in this format, not in another. You can only look up existing SID's for existing entities (Users, groups, computers, ...). I hope you're not serious when you say "other antivirus software". If you're writing antivirus software, you should have an advanced understanding of Windows security including SID's. I'm pretty sure those other AV authors are not creating random SID's. If they would be random, they wouldn't be secure because Windows won't understand them.

Comment: Today I have installed a **Gilisoft USB Lock** and when I block USB device then I check owner of my folder is exactly `S-1-5-21-123697389-1196883430-1112475604-1016` . I also check all the users and all the group in my computer using   `WMIC useraccount get name,sid`  and `WMIC group get name,sid` But NO where I see the SID `S-1-5-21-123697389-1196883430-1112475604-1016` . So I want to know How this SID is created although there is NO USER/GROUP is associated with that.

Comment: Can You explain me as I don't have much understating  about it But I need to create such SID.

Comment: @jaykr: USB devices ? The problem with that idea is that an SID in the S-1-5-21-xxx belongs to a certain PC. If you take that USB disk to another PC, the other Windows probably won't recognize the SID. It might in a domain-joined scenario, I never tried that. But since you appear to be unfamiliar with basic SID concepts I didn't mention domain-joined PC's yet.

Comment: Any SID value can be created and used in an access control entry in an object's discretionary security, but it's only useful if it's present in an access token as an enabled group. Mucking around with custom access tokens requires SeTcbPrivilege in a SYSTEM process. It can be done in a service.

Comment: @jaykr, I forgot to ask, do other users and local groups (aliases) on the system use the same 96-bit machine identifier, i.e. the three subauthority components "123697389-1196883430-1112475604"?

Comment: @MSalters I wll create different SID in different Machine programmatically & I will keep track of them. If creating custom SID is not possile then How other software take ownership with their own custome SID without creating any userName?

Comment: @ErykSun Yes I will use in access control entry in an object's discretionary security. **But the problem is that How to create SID in that format?**. Yes I enabled SeTcbPrivilege in a process.

Comment: @ErykSun Yes, All the users on the system use same three subauthority components `2258980941-3532239164-3993023005` . But Not the Group.

Comment: @ErykSun Can You please tell me How to create SID in that format to use in ACE of DACL?